# Why is my add method, not adding values into my sql database from java?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

So, I have to add a player into a list, and in the same time, to add it to my SQL Server database, but the add in the table is not happening, even though the add in the list is fine.

```
public class PlayerRepositoryJDBC {

    private Connection connection;
    private ArrayList<Player> allPlayers = new ArrayList<>();


    public ArrayList<Player> getAllPlayers() {
        return allPlayers;
    }

    public void setAllPlayers(ArrayList<Player> allPlayers) {
        this.allPlayers = allPlayers;
    }

    public PlayerRepositoryJDBC() throws SQLException {
        String connectionURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:52448;databaseName=MAP;user=user1;password=1234;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true";
        try {
            System.out.print("Connecting to the server......");
            try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL)) {
                System.out.println("Connected to the Server.");

                Statement select = connection.createStatement();
                ResultSet resultSet = select.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM PlayerMAP");
                int count = 0;
                while (resultSet.next()) {
                    count++;
                }
                if (count > 0) {
                    ResultSet result = select.executeQuery(" SELECT * FROM PlayerMAP");
                    while (result.next()) {
                        Player player = new Player
                                (result.getString("id"), result.getString("firstName"), result.getString("lastName"), result.getInt("age"), result.getString("nationality"), result.getString("position"), result.getInt("marketValue"));
                        allPlayers.add(player);
                    }
                } else {
                    String insert_string = "INSERT INTO PlayerMAP(id, firstName, lastName, age, nationality, position, marketValue) VALUES ('P1','Dan','Mic',18,'Romania','Forward',1250)";
                    Statement insert = connection.createStatement();
                    insert.executeUpdate(insert_string);
                    Player player=new Player("P1","Dan","Mic",18,"Romania","Forward",1250);
                    allPlayers.add(player);
                }
                //System.out.println(allPlayers.size());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("I am not connected to the Server");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public void add(Player entity) throws SQLException {
        allPlayers.add(entity);
        String id=entity.getId();
        String firstName=entity.getFirstName();
        String lastName=entity.getLastName();
        int age = entity.getAge();
        String nationality= entity.getNationality();
        String position=entity.getPosition();
        int marketValue=entity.getMarketValue();
        String insert_string = "INSERT INTO PlayerMAP(id, firstName, lastName, age, nationality, position, marketValue) VALUES ('"+id+"', '"+firstName+"', '"+lastName+"', '"+age+"', '"+nationality+"', '"+position+"', '"+marketValue+"')";

        Statement insert = this.connection.createStatement();
        insert.executeUpdate(insert_string);

    }
```

That's the code...
So I am expecting from my program to add an object of type Player, in my list `allPlayers`, and it should also add in my database in the table PlayerMAP. But there are no changes in my table PlayerMAP, when I check the SSMS.

Comment: `try (Connection connection` defines a local variable, therefore your class variable `connection` is empty.

Comment: Have a look [at this](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-jdbc/insert/) it covers using prepared statements for sql inserts in java to help prevent SQL Injection, it does mention PostgreSQL but the code is the same for SQL Server

Comment: Not very efficient to loop through all the players to count them: you can just do `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM PlayerMAP`. Also, it's a very bad idea to build an SQL statement when you can just use a `PreparedStatement` with parameters.

Comment: In fact, you don't even need the number of players: you just need to know if one exists.

Answer (score -1):

I see several potential issues :

1. If you already have 1 or more players inserted in your table `PlayerMap`, `count`  will always be greater than 0. So, only players already in db will be added to your `allPlayers` list
2. `ResultSet result = select.executeQuery(" SELECT * FROM PlayerMAP");` there is an extra space before the `SELECT` keyword
3. If the field `id` is the primary key of table `PlayerMAP` (as I guess), player with id "P1" will not be added in database if one with that id already exists
4. You don’t need 2 try-catch block. One is enough. Furthermore, you should catch specific exception(s) thrown and not the generic `Exception`. Here, you should catch an `SQLException` instead.
5. Did you try to add `System.out.println` (or debug points) before an after adding a new player ? It will ensure you that the SQL insert has been executed
6. If SQL insert is executed, is your database in autocommit mode ? If not, you should try to call `connection.commit()`
7. And, finally, don’t forget to close your connection after insertion

   ```
   try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL)) {
       System.out.println("Connected to the Server.");

       Statement select = connection.createStatement();
       ResultSet resultSet = select.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM PlayerMAP");
       int count = 0;
       while (resultSet.next()) {
           count++;
       }
       if (count > 0) {
           ResultSet result = select.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM PlayerMAP");//Remove extra space
           while (result.next()) {
               Player player = new Player(result.getString("id"), result.getString("firstName"),
                       result.getString("lastName"), result.getInt("age"), result.getString("nationality"),
                       result.getString("position"), result.getInt("marketValue"));
               allPlayers.add(player);
           }
       } else {
           System.out.println("in");//Add System.out (or debug point) to see if your code is executed 
           String insert_string = "INSERT INTO PlayerMAP(id, firstName, lastName, age, nationality, position, marketValue) VALUES ('P1','Dan','Mic',18,'Romania','Forward',1250)";
           Statement insert = connection.createStatement();
           insert.executeUpdate(insert_string);
           connection.commit();//Commit your insert
           Player player = new Player("P1", "Dan", "Mic", 18, "Romania", "Forward", 1250);
           allPlayers.add(player);
           System.out.println("out: " + allPlayers.size()); //Add System.out (or debug point) to see if your code is executed 
       }
       connection.close();//Close your connection
   } catch (SQLException e) {//Catche SQLException instead of Exception
       System.out.println("I am not connected to the Server");
       e.printStackTrace();
       if (connection != null)
           connection.close();//Close the connection if exception occurs
   }
   ```

   }